# Oracle equivalent of PostgreSQL's sub-select to array?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there an equivalent in Oracle to get an array from a subselect so if there is more than one row in the subselect's results there will still only be one row in the final results?

e.g.:

```
select c.name, array(select order_id from ORDER o where o.customer_id = c.id)
from CUSTOMER c;
```

Will only return one row per CUSTOMER, where the second value in each returned row is an array of order_id's.

Comment: If you are on 11.2 you might try `listagg()` (which is the equivalent to Postgres' `string_agg()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CURSOR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions006.htm#i1035107):

```
select c.name, cursor(select order_id from ORDER o where o.customer_id = c.id)
from CUSTOMER c;
```

Then your database interface will have some way of getting the results out of a cursor result.